# Get neighbor census tracts for a given census tract

Tags: api, census

I have IDs for census tracts (USA census tracts). I want to get **neighbor tracts** for a given census tract through an API call.

There are APIs for get the census tract for a given location point (*longitude, latitude*). Like that, what are the available **free APIs** for getting the neighbors?

Example:

http://www.usboundary.com/Tools/Neighbors/Census%20Tract/California/San%20Francisco%20County/Census%20Tract%20260.02/440627